# app runs fine with debug build, but crash on release build, what could be the possible reasons?

Tags: iphone, ios, release, automatic-ref-counting

I have Xcode 4.3.1, iOS 5.1, and have `ARC` turned on for building my app.

Now the app runs fine in debug build, but crash on release build. What could be the possible reason for the difference? I purely rely on `ARC` for the resource management. I looked at the crash log, it's indicating that the memory that was referencing was released already. What'll be the common pitfalls that could cause the problem on retail build, when using `ARC`?

The following is what I got from crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6f636552
Crashed Thread:  0
```

**EDIT**

The app's deployment target is iOS 5.0. I do use internet connections, the current crash happens on the time when "rendering" the data returned from web service in order to show on a `UITableViewController`. The whole app is using `ARC`, except a few source files from 3rd party for which I have `ARC` turned off.

Comment: Pls give more hints, deployment target?are you using connections to Internet ? All your class use ARC or only some of them?

Comment: done, please see updates above

Comment: I think that is better to test your app using zombie instruments on the sim. The fact that you are mixing ARC and non-ARC classes could lead in some problem using delegation or notification patterns. Is difficult to understand why is happening only on the device and not on the sim, but probably is due to the hardware differences between the two.

Comment: oh, the difference lies in release build and debug build, not device vs simulator.

Comment: I see, but I think that it could be something like that anyway. If you do not post the entire crash log it will be really hard to imagine what's happening. I'm thinking about a un-nilled pointer called asynchronously by a connection callbacks, so a Zombie. The problem that  is happening only in release is hard to understand totally but probably due to different run loop modes, are you using preprocessor definition? like '#ifdef debug' etc or seething like that? are you using network connections on multithreaded environment?

Comment: Interesting...the invalid address that it's reporting is a character string: 'Reco'.  This is probably not a coincidence and looks like more evidence for released memory being re-used.  (I've heard that it's possible to set up a release build to run in Instruments but I haven't done it.)

Comment: Are the sources of your network requests the same on Debug and Release? I often use preprocessor conditionals (`#ifdef`) to set my local and production WebService depending on the build mode. Also, ARC is not 100% leak proof. Some unwell handled requests to the internet could cause leaks. I suggest only using asynchronous requests, for those synchronous ones may just stop responding in some circumstances and cause such leaks.

Comment: Code optimization and other compiler/linker flags are different by default between debug and release.  This means that the binaries are different.  Try running a build with the exact same options as in release (but with and without debug symbols) and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever this happens to me it seems to be because release builds are more aggressive about clearing up weak references. If you mistakenly assign something to a weak property (for example, if you're adding subviews that you will also hold weak references to) before you have any strong reference to it, this can work on debug and fail on release. For example (pseudocode)

```
@property (weak) UILabel * label;
...
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
[self.view addSubview:self.label];
...
self.label.text = @"hello";
```

I've seen this cause bad access crashes on release builds and go unnoticed on debug.

Comment: yes, this could definitly lead to a crash and is a mistake. you should never ONLY have a weak ref.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have the answer but I'm going to list a few hunches for you to try:

- Make sure you are not passing objects into methods without a "handle" on it on your side. And example would be passing a handler class instance to a method that expects a delegate. The method doesn't retain that instance and so it gets released before it even calls the method.
- Check your pre-compiler macros that they are safe for both DEBUG & RELEASE builds. A good example is having an `if` statement over a macro that is removed in release builds and the `if` statement doesn't cover it with curly braces.
- If you depend on compiler definitions to enable/disable certain parts of your code (through the use of `#if` conditions) make sure the needed ones are set in your build configuration.

If I can think of more, I'll try to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a different target for release and debug? Check whether all the files are correctly referenced for the release target.

In our case, a category on UIButton was not seen by the release target. An ad-Hoc build went just fine, until someone invoked a method implemented by that category. Since we did not store an archive from the Ad-Hoc build, there was no way to debug a crash. (lesson learned)

Not sure whether it is listed as `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in a crash log, but could help someone to identify their release-specific crash.